# How to get the value from rows and columns from text file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, columns

I am working on a bash project. I need to get all the values (one at a time because I will be using them somewhere else) from a text file. The text file I will be getting is structured like this:

```
Report:
-----------
Name  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
row1  val1     val2     val3     val4     
row2  val5     val6     val7     val8     
row3  val9     val10    val11    val12
```

There are no fixed amount of rows and columns so I will need something general. How do I retrieve each val one by one in bash? Thanks.

Comment: Does the val means any value(a combination of numbers or letters)?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes a value can be either a number, letters or combination of both

Comment: Please don't [crosspost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290651/how-do-i-get-the-value-from-any-row-or-column-from-a-text-file-in-bash)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process content of a file line by line, using `bash` `while` loop:

```
i=1

while IFS= read -a line; do
  printf "Line number %d:\n" $i
  printf "%s\n" "${line[@]}"
  let i++
done < "file.txt"
```

Each line is stored in array `line`, you can get each element of array `line` by syntax:

```
echo "${line[n]}"
```

where `n` is the order of element in array.

Answer (score 3):

And through awk command,

```
$ awk '/^Report|^-----|^Name/ {next}{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}' file
val1
val2
val3
val4
val5
val6
val7
val8
val9
val10
val11
val12
```

It skips the line starts with `Report,---,Name` and it prints all the values from the second column to the end for each line. The values are printed in a newline.